# Having an issue with non int multiplication

Tags: python

I am having an issue with my back propagation algorithm. I am having a non int can't be multiplied. Here is the error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-42-6fc9bb58fbab> in <module>()
      8 
      9 
---> 10 neuralNetLearn(l, data, r,  w1, w2, v)

1 frames
<ipython-input-36-83534fc81b83> in function(data, w)
     13   while (i <= len(X)-1):
     14     while (j <= len(w)-1):
---> 15       val = X[i]*w[j]
     16       valArray.append(val)
     17       j += 1

TypeError: can't multiply sequence by non-int of type 'list'
```

here is the function itself:

```
def function(data, w):
  X = data

  F = lambda x,y,z: x+y+z
  valArray = []
  newNode = []
  val = 0
  sumVal = 0
  i = 0
  j = 0
  

  while (i <= len(X)-1): 
    while (j <= len(w)-1):
      val = X[i]*w[j]
      valArray.append(val)
      j += 1

    sumVal = F(val1,val2,val3)
    newNode.append(sumVal)
    i += 1

  return newNode
```

Here is the call within the function neuralLearn:

```
z = [1, 0, 0]
while(i <= 10000):
    z[1] = function(data, w)
    z[1] = logistic(function)
    z[1] = hardThresh(z)
    z[2] = function(data, 2)
    z[2] = logistic(function)
    z[2] = hardThresh(z)
```

Here is the main call with the data:

```
#Data = [ ( (0,0), 0 ), ( (0,1), 1 ), ( (1,0), 1), ( (1,1), 0 ) ]
l = 0.001
data = [(1,0,0), (1,0,1), (1,1,0), (1,1,1)]
r = [0,1,1,0]
w1 = randomizer(4)
w2 = randomizer(4)
v = randomizer(4)


neuralNetLearn(l, data, r,  w1, w2, v)
```

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: That error indicates that `w[j]` is evaluating to a list, not a number, which means that `w` is a 2D-list. That means you're trying to multiply a list by a list, which as the error mentions, doesn't work. Did you mean to do something like `X[i] * w[j][some_other_number]`?

Comment: oh ok yeah it was a 2d array. I didn't see that until now. Thank you!